# jquery ajax animation not working while trying to add an item to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im doing a single TODO app,i have the basic functions to add and edit an item.

When i add an item it reloads the page and add the item, but i wanted to add an simple fadeIn or background flash to the recently added item but for some reason doesn't work.

Here is my index.php where i can add the item:

```
<?php include_once "_partials/header.php" ?>

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>VERY MUCH TODO LIST</h1>
</div>

<?php $data = $database->select('items', [ 'id' , 'text'] ); ?>

<ul class="list-group col-sm-6">
    <?php
        foreach ( $data as $item ) {
            echo '<li class="list-group-item">';
            echo $item['text'];
            echo '  <div class="controls pull-right">';
            echo '      <a href="edit.php?id=' . $item["id"] . '" class="edit-link">edit</a>';
            echo '      <a href="delete.php?id=' . $item["id"] . '"  class="delete-link text-muted glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>';
            echo '  </div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<form id="add-form" class="col-sm-6" action="_inc/add-item.php" method="post">
    <p class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="text" rows="3" placeholder="is there [ /watch?v=GO3wwqikkF0 ] ?"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="form-group">
        <input class="btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" value="add new thing">
    </p>
</form>
```

Here is the add-item.php:

```
<?php

// include
require 'config.php';

// add new stuff
$id = $database->insert('items', [
    'text' => $_POST['message']
]);

// success
if ( $id ) {
    header("Location:  $site_url/index.php");
}
```

Here is the app.js , here you can see that i have the li.hide and then some fancy thing added to. But even if i change the .appendTo() to .prependTo() it doesnt work.

```
(function($){
var form = $('#add-form'),
    input = form.find('#text');

    input.val('').focus();

form.on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var req = $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize()
    });

    req.done(function(data){
        if ( data === 'success' ) {
            var li = $('<li class="list-group-item">' + input.val() + '</li>');
            
                li.hide()
                    .appendTo('.list-group')
                    .css({backgroundColor: '#00bc8c'})
                    .delay(200)
                    .animate({backgroundColor: '#303030'});

                input.val('').focus();
        };
    });
});

input.on('keypress', function(event){
    if ( event.which === 13 ) {
        form.submit();
        return false;
    }
})
}(jQuery));
```

and here is the config.php :

```
<?php

// show all errors
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

// Require Composer's autoloader.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Using Medoo namespace
use Medoo\Medoo;

// Connect the database.
$database = new Medoo([
    'type' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'todo',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root'
]);

//global variables
$site_url = 'http://localhost:8888';

// Enjoy
$database->insert('account', [
    'user_name' => 'foo',
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com'
]);

$data = $database->select('account', [
    'user_name',
    'email'
], [
    'user_id' => 50
]);

// echo json_encode($data);

// [{
//    "user_name" : "foo",
//    "email" : "foo@bar.com",
// }]
```

Comment: .animate without plugins can only animate numeric values. background color isn't among them. Do any other animations function?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, `if ( data === 'success' ) {` is probably never true. just remove the if statement, you're already in success.

Answer (score -1):

To animate a color, like `backgroundColor`, you need to also import `jQuery UI`. As stated in [their documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some
> non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated.

This would apply to the backgroundColor transformation you're attempting. Here's the script tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Take a look in the snippet below. I also added `fadeIn()`

```js
(function($) {

  var form = $('#add-form'),
    input = form.find('#text');
  input.val('').focus();
  form.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    var li = $('<li class="list-group-item">' + input.val() + '</li>');

    li.hide()
      .appendTo('.list-group')
      .css({
        backgroundColor: '#00bc8c'
      })
      .fadeIn()
      .delay(500)
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: '#303030',
        color: '#ffffff'
      }, 1000);

    input.val('').focus();

  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="list-group col-sm-6">
</ul>
<form id="add-form" class="col-sm-6" action="_inc/add-item.php" method="post">
  <p class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="text" rows="3" placeholder="is there [ /watch?v=GO3wwqikkF0 ] ?"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p class="form-group">
    <input class="btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit" value="add new thing">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: nope did not fix it.

Comment: @qNecro - Ok, updated my answer with new info and a testable snippet. Thx

Comment: @qnecro - did this end up working for you?